# Executing external Python program in Sikuli script

Tags: python, automation, sikuli, sikuli-script

I am trying to call a python program which just sends me a text on my phone from a Sikuli script.I am a beginner and my goal is to receive a text when a certain loop is finished, but I don't know how to call on it from the Sikuli script. This is a small part of my code from Sikuli so far.

```
while (something):
     if (randomThing):
       something = False


subprocess.Popen("python SendSMS.py")
```

I get an OS error saying no such file or directory. Is there a better way to do this? or what am I doing wrong here? I am using Mac.

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.Popen()` will look for SendSMS.py in same directory but if your script is not in that directory you will get find not found error which is totally expected. As a fix you will need to provide whole path to your script instead of just `python SendSMS.py` replace it with `python /home/my_user/SendSMS.py` and check if it works.

Comment: my python file is located  /Users/[myUser]/SendSms.py   -- and I get this error: [error] OSError ( Cannot run program "python /SendSMS.py" (in directory "/Users/[myUser]"): error=2, No such file or directory ). I am specifying the correct path here right?

Comment: are you using windows ? please check file name is it SendSms.py or SendSMS.py ?

Comment: I am using Mac. I am specifying the correct spelling "SendSMS" in subprocess.Popen("python /SendSMS.py"), which is the same as the python file name

Comment: so replace `Popen("python /SendSMS.py")` with `Popen("python /home/my_user/SendSMS.py")`

Comment: That didn't work as well. I fixed the problem now by using subprocess.call(["python", "SendSMS.py"])..

Comment: glad to know your problem has been fixed!